# How to create a curl loop to make my code more compact?

Tags: shell, curl

I am intending to make a small web scraper script:

I have a shell script scrape.sh which I have made executable with `chmod 755`

`curl` is used to scrape the data ( I intent to scrape 30,000 url's )

Content of scrape.sh:

```
        curl https://example.com/something/UID1 --output UID1.html
        curl https://example.com/something/UID2 --output UID2.html
        curl https://example.com/something/UID3 --output UID3.html
        curl https://example.com/something/UID4 --output UID4.html
    ...
        curl https://example.com/something/UID30000 --output UID30000.html
```

Instead of using 30.000 lines of code in my scrape.sh, what is a more compact way of getting this done?

Comment: may I ask where you get these UID's from? are they in a file? can they be programmatically generated?

Comment: `curl` is not a scraper. It just downloads the website's html-source. So in your _'scrape.sh'_ you forgot to include the actual HTML-parser you're using to extract the desired info.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to generate sequential numbers in shell.

You can use `seq` command with for loop:

```
for id in $(seq 1 100); do
  echo "id is ${id}"
done
```

In many modern shells (like bash, zsh, ...) you can use for loop more idiomatically:

```
for (( id = 0; id < 100; id++ )); do
  echo "id is ${id}"
done
```

In those shells you can also use brace expansion.

```
for id in {1..100}; do
  echo "id is $id"
done
```

As a side note, brace expansions are way cooler than this - you can use prefixes (`echo abc{1..5}`), you can do sequences of letters (`echo {a..z}`), or even permutations (`echo {1..3}{a..c}{1..3}`).